# Angular как узнать предыдущий маршрут?

Tags: маршрутизация, angular, angular-routing

Хочу в OnInit хуке компонента выполнять определенное действие в зависимости от того, с какого маршрута пользователь сюда пришел. Как мне узнать имя (или еще какой-то идентификатор) предыдущего маршрута?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы используете `rxjs > 5.5`, то там есть поддержка так называемых `pipeable operators`, `pipe` преобразовывает `Observable` в `Stream` `node.js`, и конечно будет ошибка, что `property pairwise does't exist on type Observable<Event>`. одним `pairwise` тут не обойтись, потому что `Router` имеет свой жизненный цикл `NavigationStart => NavigationEnd`, как вариант используйте еще `filter`:

```
import { Router, RouterEvent, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

import { filter, pairwise } from 'rxjs/operators';

.....

@Component({ ... })
class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.router.events.pipe<RouterEvent>(
            filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
            pairwise()
        ).subscribe(([previous, current]: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {
            console.log(previous.url);
            console.log(current.url);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [парный оператор](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pairwise) для получения предыдущего и текущего событий, что является хорошей идеей.

```
this.router.events.pairwise().subscribe((event) => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: IDE выдает ошибку, что свойство pairwise не существует в типе Observable<Event>

Comment: Это свойство доступно в более поздних версиях.

Comment: В поздних версиях чего? Если rxjs, то у меня 6.2.2. А если typescript, то какой-то компонент ангуляра (не помню какой, но при сборке консоль ошибку выдает) просит версию 2.7.2.

Comment: Из чего состоит проект?

Comment: Боюсь, я Вас не понял. Вы хотите увидеть мои зависимости?

Comment: Я не знаю, чего вы хотите понять, вы получили ответ на вопрос.